# ActionScripts3 Movie clip click event issue

Tags: actionscript-3, animate-cc

I'm trying to write some code for a movie clip to make a clickable area in stage in specific frame, There is an error that i couldn't find what is that error.

"**btn_SETTINGS**" is a movie clip.

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Stop at frame 72 (STORES PAGE)
gotoAndStop(73);

//Button SETTINGS Click
function goto_SETTINGS(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(74);
}
trace("button:",btn_SETTINGS); 
btn_SETTINGS.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto_SETTINGS);
```

[image]
Error:

```
 button: null
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at APPRAYAN_fla::MainTimeline/frame72()[APPRAYAN_fla.MainTimeline::frame72:13]
```

Comment: Your error tells your where it is. Frame 72. Line 12. MainTimeLine. What code do you have there?

Comment: the code is in Frame 72

Comment: That's what I just said. I'm asking *what* is on line 12 in frame 72

Comment: After 72 frame(3 sec) Main window show on frame 73, there is a movieclip"btn_SETTINGS"

Comment: Line 12: btn_SETTINGS.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto_SETTINGS);

Comment: Ok directly above that type `trace("button:",btn_SETTINGS);` and tell me what it prints to your output window.

Comment: I updated codes and errors

Comment: put that trace above line 12

Comment: "button: null" shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your frame number and code, That function and event listener looking for object "btn_SETTINGS" but there is no object in frame 72, separate your code to different frames.

Frame 72:

```
gotoAndStop(73);
```

Frame 73:

```
//Button SETTINGS Click
function goto_SETTINGS(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(74);
}
btn_SETTINGS.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto_SETTINGS);
```